# Apply jQuery to dynamically inserted divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I am writing a userscript using jQuery. I am trying to change the content of the divs with the class `foo` so it contains `bar`. With a static list of elements, I can do it using `$(document).ready()`:

```js
// The userscript
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".foo").text("bar");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
</div>
```

However, I can't figure out how to replace the text of divs that get inserted dynamically:

```js
// The userscript
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".foo").text("bar");
});

// A function to dynamically add another div:
$("#add").click(function() {
  $("<div></div>").text("foo").addClass("foo").appendTo("#content");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  <div class="foo">Div 1</div>
  <div class="foo">Div 2</div>
</div>
<button id="add" type="button">Add</button> // Click to
```

Using `$(document).ready()` only works on the *statically* inserted divs, as those are the only ones there when the document is loaded.

How can I make the divs that are *dynamically* added to `#content` get their content changed to `bar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note sure why you don't just change the `$("<div></div>").text("foo")` to `$("<div></div>").text("bar")`;

But the code in your `$(document).ready()` only runs once.

so do something like this.

```
// The userscript
$(document).ready(function() {
  footext();
});

// A function to dynamically add another div:
$("#add").click(function() {
  $("<div></div>").text("foo").addClass("foo").appendTo("#content");
  footext();
});

function footext() {
  $(".foo").text("bar");
}
```

**Demo**

```js
// The userscript
$(document).ready(function() {
  footext();
});

// A function to dynamically add another div:
$("#add").click(function() {
  $("<div></div>").text("foo").addClass("foo").appendTo("#content");
  footext();
});

function footext() {
  $(".foo").text("bar");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  <div class="foo">Div 1</div>
  <div class="foo">Div 2</div>
</div>
<button id="add" type="button">Add</button> // Click to
```

You can also use `DOMNodeInserted`

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.foo', function () {
      $(this).text("bar");
});
```

**Demo**

```js
// The userscript
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".foo").text("bar");
});

// A function to dynamically add another div:
$("#add").click(function() {
  $("<div></div>").text("foo").addClass("foo").appendTo("#content");
});

$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.foo', function () {
      $(this).text("bar");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  <div class="foo">Div 1</div>
  <div class="foo">Div 2</div>
</div>
<button id="add" type="button">Add</button> // Click to
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
`$(".foo").text("bar");`
```

inside the button click function.

```js
// The userscript
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".foo").text("bar");
});

// A function to dynamically add another div:
$("#add").click(function() {
  $("<div></div>").text("foo").addClass("foo").appendTo("#content");
   $(".foo").text("bar");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  <div class="foo">Div 1</div>
  <div class="foo">Div 2</div>
</div>
<button id="add" type="button">Add</button> // Click to
```